# Query takes more than 40 seconds to execute

Tags: mysql, sql

This query takes more than 40 seconds to execute on a table that has 200k rows

```
SELECT 
     my_robots.*, 
     (
        SELECT count(id) 
        FROM hpsi_trading 
        WHERE estado <= 1 and idRobot = my_robots.id
     ) as openorders,
     apikeys.apikey, 
     apikeys.apisecret 
FROM my_robots, apikeys 
WHERE estado <= 1 
     and idRobot = '2' 
     and ready = '1' 
     and apikeys.id = my_robots.idApiKey 
     and (my_robots.id LIKE '%0' 
          OR my_robots.id LIKE '%1' 
          OR my_robots.id LIKE '%2')
```

I know it is because of the count inside the query, but how could i fix this efficiently.

Edit: Explain

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: show output of `explain` your query.

Comment: edited. with the explain

Comment: Using two FROM clause is not avisable. Use `INNER JOIN ` instead

Comment: can you also pre-qualify ALL your table.column references. (Estado, idRobot, ready) to prevent ambiguity and guessing at table association (myRObots, apikeys)

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY` instead

```
SELECT my_robots.*, 
       count(id) as openorders, 
       apikeys.apikey, 
       apikeys.apisecret 
FROM my_robots
JOIN apikeys ON apikeys.id = my_robots.idApiKey
LEFT JOIN hpsi_trading ON hpsi_trading.idRobot = my_robots.id and estado <= 1
WHERE estado <= 1 and 
      idRobot = '2' and 
      ready = '1' and 
      (
          my_robots.id LIKE '%0' OR 
          my_robots.id LIKE '%1' OR 
          my_robots.id LIKE '%2'
      ) 
GROUP BY my_robots.id, apikeys.apikey, apikeys.apisecret
```

Use explicit `JOIN` syntax. Some indexes will be needed to run it fast, however, the database structure is not clear from your post (and from your query as well).

Comment: small comment - there is an extra 'and' operator around "ready = '1'". Tried to edit the answer but SO requires at least 6 characters to be modified...

Answer (score 0):

The explain plan shows that the largest pain is selecting the data from the table *hpsi_trading*.

The challenge from the database's point of view is that the query contains a correlated subquery in the SELECT clause, which needs to be executed once for each result of the outer query (after filtering).

Replacing this subquery with a JOIN + GROUP BY will require MySQL to join between all these records (inflate) and only then deflate the data using GROUP BY, which might take time.

Instead, I would extract the subquery to a temporary table, which is grouped during creation, index it and join to it. That way, the subquery will run once, using a quick covering index, it will already group the data and only then join it to the other table.

This far, it's all pros. But, the con here is that extracting a subquery to a temporary table might require more effort on the development side.

Please try this version and let me know if it helped (if not, please provide a fresh EXPLAIN plan screenshot):

Creating the temp table:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp1 AS 
      SELECT idRobot, COUNT(id) as openorders
      FROM   hpsi_trading
      WHERE  estado <= 1
      GROUP BY idRobot;
```

The modified query:

```
SELECT 
    my_robots.*,
    temp1.openorders,
    apikeys.apikey,
    apikeys.apisecret
FROM
    my_robots,
    apikeys
    LEFT JOIN temp1 on temp1.idRobot = my_robots.id
WHERE
    estado <= 1 AND idRobot = '2'
        AND ready = '1'
        AND apikeys.id = my_robots.idApiKey
        AND (my_robots.id LIKE '%0'
        OR my_robots.id LIKE '%1'
        OR my_robots.id LIKE '%2')
```

The indexes to add for this solution (I assumed from logic that *estado*, *idRobot* and *ready* are from the apikeys table. If that's not the case, let me know and I'll adjust the indexes):

```
ALTER TABLE `temp1` ADD INDEX `temp1_index_1` (idRobot);
ALTER TABLE `hpsi_trading` ADD INDEX `hpsi_trading_index_1` (idRobot, estado, id);
ALTER TABLE `apikeys` ADD INDEX `apikeys_index_1` (`idRobot`, `ready`, `id`, `estado`);
ALTER TABLE `my_robots` ADD INDEX `my_robots_index_1` (`idApiKey`);
```